# found nil while populating modal from JSON parsing in Swift4

Tags: json, swift, swift4

I'd like to parse the following retrieved data using Swift 4.

> {"bannerCategory":{"name":"","apps":[{"ImageName":"enhancedWith3dTouch"},{"ImageName":"drSeussBanner"},{"ImageName":"indieGameBanner"},{"ImageName":"clashRoyaleBanner"}],"type":""},"categories":[{"name":"Best
>   New Apps","apps":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Disney Build It:
>   Frozen","Category":"Entertainment","Price":3.99,"ImageName":"frozen"},{"Name":"Spot
>   - the best places according to experts and friends","Category":"Travel","ImageName":"spot"},{"Name":"Dine - More
>   Dates, Not Swipes","Category":"Social
>   Networking","ImageName":"dine"},{"Name":"Today: Habit tracker for your
>   daily goals and routines","Category":"Health \u0026
>   Fitness","ImageName":"today"},{"Id":1,"Name":"Disney Build It:
>   Frozen","Category":"Entertainment","Price":3.99,"ImageName":"frozen"},{"Name":"Spot
>   - the best places according to experts and friends","Category":"Travel","ImageName":"spot"},{"Name":"Dine - More
>   Dates, Not Swipes","Category":"Social
>   Networking","ImageName":"dine"},{"Name":"Today: Habit tracker for your
>   daily goals and routines","Category":"Health \u0026
>   Fitness","ImageName":"today"}],"type":""},{"name":"Best New
>   Games","apps":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Telepaint","Category":"Games","Price":2.99,"ImageName":"telepaint"},{"Name":"Dirac","Category":"Games","Price":1.99,"ImageName":"dirac"},{"Name":"Clash
>   Royale","Category":"Games","ImageName":"clashroyale"},{"Name":"Beat
>   Stomper","Category":"Games","Price":1.99,"ImageName":"beatstomper"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Telepaint","Category":"Games","Price":2.99,"ImageName":"telepaint"},{"Name":"Dirac","Category":"Games","Price":1.99,"ImageName":"dirac"},{"Name":"Clash
>   Royale","Category":"Games","ImageName":"clashroyale"},{"Name":"Beat
>   Stomper","Category":"Games","Price":1.99,"ImageName":"beatstomper"}],"type":""},{"name":"50%
>   Off for a Limited
>   Time","apps":[{"ImageName":"luminocity"},{"ImageName":"theroom"},{"ImageName":"badland"},{"ImageName":"shadowmatic"},{"ImageName":"luminocity"},{"ImageName":"theroom"},{"ImageName":"badland"},{"ImageName":"shadowmatic"}],"type":"large"},{"name":"More
>   Games You Might Like","apps":[{"Name":"Summoners
>   War","Category":"Games","ImageName":"summonerswar"},{"Name":"Angry
>   Birds
>   Space","Category":"Games","Price":0.99,"ImageName":"angrybirdsspace"},{"Name":"Star
>   Wars™: Commander - Worlds in
>   Conflict","Category":"Games","ImageName":"starwars"},{"Name":"Death
>   Worm","Category":"Games","Price":2.99,"ImageName":"deathworm"}],"type":""}]}

modal object to retrieve data

```
struct FeaturedApps: Codable {

    var bannerCategory: AppCategory?
    var categories: [AppCategory]?



    struct AppCategory: Codable {

       let name : String?
       let apps : [App]?
       let type: String?

        struct App : Codable {

            let id: Int?
            let name: String?
            let category : String?
            let imageName : String?
            let price : Float?

        }   
     } 
}
```

codes for JSON parsing

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let jsonUrl = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/appstore/featured"
                guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrl) else { return }


       let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error)  in


            guard let data = data else { return }

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            do {


                let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode(FeaturedApps.self, from: data)
                print(courses)



            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
     } 
}
```

That yields the following output:

> FeaturedApps(bannerCategory:
>   Optional(JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory(name: Optional(""),
>   apps: Optional([JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil,
>   name: nil, category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil)]), type: Optional(""))),
>   categories: Optional([JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory(name:
>   Optional("Best New Apps"), apps:
>   Optional([JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name:
>   nil, category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil)]), type: Optional("")),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory(name: Optional("Best New
>   Games"), apps:
>   Optional([JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name:
>   nil, category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil)]), type: Optional("")),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory(name: Optional("50% Off for a
>   Limited Time"), apps:
>   Optional([JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name:
>   nil, category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil)]), type:
>   Optional("large")), JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory(name:
>   Optional("More Games You Might Like"), apps:
>   Optional([JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name:
>   nil, category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil),
>   JsonParseSwift4.FeaturedApps.AppCategory.App(id: nil, name: nil,
>   category: nil, imageName: nil, price: nil)]), type: Optional(""))]))

Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong and getting nil values ?

Comment: Please compare the keys and corresponding properties. Hint: case sensitivity matters. Another way to catch errors is to declare the properties as non-optionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your properties should be the same as it is in the JSON response. If a property uses different naming convention(case and/or spelling), it is treated as not found and is assigned a value of nil (if it is optional) or the program crashes (if it is required)